# python code to enroll and verify secugen fingerprint

Tags: python, fingerprint

I am following https://github.com/openabis/openabis-secugen for python binding to enrol and verify for secugen hamster 20 but could not initialize due to unknown data type.
requesting to see above link and guide me how to send config in class declaration.

Thanking You,

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: s=SecuGen(a)
  File "C:\Users\Yuvraj\Desktop\secugen\secugen.py", line 301, in __init__
    self.secu_level = config.get("SECUGEN_MATCH_SECURITY_LEVEL", self.SECURITY_LEVEL_NORMAL)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'